# Project import Problem

Tags: android

I am new to this android development i imported a project in eclipse when i try to run the 
project it is giving the following error,

Launch configuration Bootstrap references non-existing project Projectname.

Please guide me.

Thanks,
Balaram.

Answer (score 0):

try this

Select File -> New -> Project, choose Android Project , and then click Next.
Select "Create project from existing source". select